# Webhooks in Bitcoin Transactions - How to Apply Business Logics?

Tags: javascript, html, blockchain, webhooks, bitcoin

I want to start accepting Bitcoin on my website.

In order to do that, I wrote the following piece of code, but I truly struggle to understand how I can implement proper business logic after that the transaction is completed.

Here is the code:

```
<html>

<head>

    <title>Pay with Bitcoin</title>

    <script>

            //Gets the URL of the Webpage and gets the price value of this transaction in USD.
            //For simplicity Here the Value is passed in the URL.
            //However in production you wanna use POST instead of GET.

            const myUrl = window.location.href;
            const url = new URL(myUrl);
            const usdPrice = url.searchParams.get("price");

            //This is the function where all the magin happens

            const showQR = () => {

                    //URL of the api which will provide us with current BTC exchange rate

                    const apiUrl = "https://blockchain.info/ticker";

                    const hr = new XMLHttpRequest();

                    hr.open('GET', apiUrl, true);

                    hr.onreadystatechange = function(){

                    //Make sure the API sent a valid response

                        if(hr.readyState == 4){

                            let ticker = JSON.parse(hr.responseText);

                            //Get last BTC/USD exchange value from the API , then convert Price from USD to BTC 

                            let BTCprice = ticker.USD.last;

                            let btcToPay = usdPrice / BTCprice;

                            //Make sure you have just 8 decimal points in your BTC price!!

                            btcToPay = btcToPay.toFixed(8);

                            //Use google API (or other...) to create the QR code. Pass on your btc public address and 
                            //the amount (btc price) dynamically created. Message and label parameters can be dynamic too.

                            let qrurl = "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=250x250&cht=qr&chl=bitcoin:1BAnkZn1qW42uRTyG2sCRN9F5kgtfb5Bci?amount="+btcToPay+"%26label=CarRental%26message=BookingID123456";

                            //Populate the 'btc' DIV with QR code and other info...
                            document.getElementById('btc').innerHTML = "<img src=" +qrurl+"><br> <span class = 'greenMoney'>" + usdPrice + " usd / " + btcToPay + " BTC </span>";

                            }

                    }

                hr.send();

            };

    </script>

</head>

<body onload = "showQR()">

    <h1>Pay with BitCoin</h1>

    <div id = "btc">

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

This code does the following:

1. Gets current USD/BTC exchange rate using the blockchain API.
2. takes the price in USD for the URL and converts it into BTC
3. generates a QR code using google API.
4. Embeds the price, label and message into the QR code
5. Renders the QR code in a DIV

I ve also set up a web hook service which will be listening to new transactions happening in the specified wallet address. Then a callback to my server is made, by mean of a POST request.

The problem is: the label and message parameters passed to the QR code will not be written in the blockchain.

They are just a handy reference for the customer to remind him what that specific transaction paid for.

As a result the callback to my server is practically useless.

In fact, the callback doesn't return any Booking Id or any other piece of information which could help me to understand who paid for what. Needless to say, in this scenario no business logic is possible: I can't update the order status on my DB, I can't send a confirmation email to the right customer.

How can I embed relevant information (e.g. Booking ID) into the BTC payment, ideally through the QR code?

If this is possible, how can I retrieve this information later on when my server receives the callback informing me that a new payment was made to my BTC wallet?

Answer (score -1):

In short, you can't.

When accepting payments, you are supposed to give each invoice a new BTC address. This way, when you receive notification of an incoming transaction, you can check the receiving address to see which invoice is being paid, and compare the received amount against the expected amount.

*Note*

Technically, you could embed stuff like a order ID into an OP_RETURN. However, most wallets don't support transactions like that, and any users who want to pay you from an exchange account would be unable to comply.

Answer (score -1):

@Raghav Sood thank you for your input which routed me to the right direction.

Using NodeJS/Express/MongoDB in the backend, I managed to implement a solution which I would like to share here.

Before starting, I wanna make a big disclaimer: this solution is not the only one, it is not the best one, it is not the fastest and probably it is not the most elegant.

Anyway, this solution has the advantage of not relying on packaged third parties solutions. This is in line with the spirit of the whole "no intermediation" philosophy of the bitcoin community. Most imortantly, your  XPub always stay in your server and is NOT shared with any external service, which is probably the wisest approach.

Having said that, here is how one can show dynamic unique BTC addresses to customers:

1. First of all , I put in place a counter which keeps track of how many btc addresses were created for customers from a my HD wallet.

This is important to make sure than you never present the same address twice to customers, which is good for privacy of all parties and also for the sake of implementing business logic in your app.

In order to do this, I store a "counter value" into my DB. Everytime someone visits the BTC payment page, this value is retrived from mongo using a "dealCount" function and is assigned to a "serialPay" variable, which is equal to the value gotten from Mongo + 1. In the backend, the code would be something like this:

```
`function dealCount(){`

        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){

            Deal.find({_id: "ID_OF_OBJ_WHERE_YOU_STORE_COUNTER"}, function(err, data){

              if(err){

                console.log(err);

              }

                resolve(data[0].serialDeal + 1);

            })

        })

      };
```

The new value obtained (which later on will be saved again into Mongo in order to keep track of addresses created) is used to generate the new BTC public address for the customer at hand. If you keep reading you will see how.

To create new public addresses dynamically, one needs the xPub Key of his or her HD Wallet. If one is coding in NodeJS there are a couple of libraries (which can be imported into the server) that will enable this operation rather easily: bitcoinjs-lib and/or bitcore-lib. Personally I opted for Bitcore-lib, because there are less dependencies to deal with and I found the supporting material easier to digest.

Codewise, address generation goes as follows:

```
        const bitcore = require('bitcore-lib');

        app.post("/pay.html", urlencodedParser, function(req, res){

        let serialPay = dealCount();

        serialPay.then(function(serialPay){

          const pub = new bitcore.HDPublicKey('INSERT_HERE_YOUR_XPUB_KEY');

          let derivedHdPk = pub.derive('m/0/'+serialPay);

          let derivedPk = derivedHdPk.publicKey;

          let myDynAddress = new bitcore.Address(derivedPk);

          res.render('pay', {myDynAddress: myDynAddress});

        });

      });
```

2. Then, using EJS as a templating engine, I could easily make the receiving bitcoin address dynamic in the front-end (/pay.ejs):

   ```
   let myDynAddress = "<%=myDynAddress%>";
   let qrurl = "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=250x250&cht=qr&chl=bitcoin:"+myDynAddress+"?amount="+btcToPay+"%26label=CarRental";
   ```

   This will generate the QR Code Dynamically. In the original question, one can see how to render that into the webpage. In the meantime one should also put in place a function to store the updated "serialPay" counter back to the DB.
3. At this point one should only start monitoring incoming (non-confirmed) payments to the dynamic BTC address generated. A simple way to do it, is using the blockchain.info websocket API. When the payment arrives, things go forward as suggested by @Raghav Sood: one checks the incoming transaction making sure the customer paid the right amount to the right address.

Now you know who paid for what and all sorts of business logics can be triggered.